# Giant alien flies into the solar system; the rocky planets are its eggs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in an anthology borrowed from the local public library around 1980.  (The book itself may have been older.)

The story begins with the global sensation of a massive object entering our solar system from interstellar space.  As it approaches the Sun it maneuvers which indicates it is an actual alien visitor, not just a random rogue planet.  (It is of planetary scale.)

I believe that when it is viewed through a telescope it has massive wings that it uses to steer using the Sun's light.

The alien brakes into a solar orbit and matches its orbit to Mercury.  Humanity watches, wondering what it is doing, and then the crust of Mercury starts to crack.  The entire crust is dislodged, and a smaller version of the alien spreads its wings.  The alien begins to spiral out to Venus' orbit, and people on Earth start freaking out.

Massive projects are started to drill through the Earth's crust and set off hydrogen bombs in the hope of killing the hatchling before it destroys the Earth.  Meanwhile Venus hatches, and the (now 3) aliens start towards Earth.

The story ends with the narrator saying something like "this morning the Earth began to knock."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

["And Lo! The Bird"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69112), a 1950 short story by [Nelson S. Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_S._Bond), was also the answer to the question [Giant Bird in Space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82353/giant-bird-in-space). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?69112). It inspired the cover of [this one](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35660):

[image: The Best Animal Stories of Science Fiction and Fantasy]

**The story begins with the global sensation of a massive object entering our solar system from interstellar space.**

The story is narrated by the newspaper reporter who broke the story. In this passage he is interviewing the astronomer who made the discovery:

> "A bird," he said.
>
> I glanced at him in swift surprise. "A bird?" I felt like smiling, but the look in his eyes did not encourage mirth.
>
> "A bird," he repeated. "Far in the depths of space. The telescope was directed toward Pluto, farthermost planet of our solar system. A body almost four thousand millions of miles from Earth.
>
> "And at that distance—" he spoke with a painful deliberation—"at that incredible distance, I saw a bird!"

**The alien brakes into a solar orbit and matches its orbit to Mercury. Humanity watches, wondering what it is doing, and then the crust of Mercury starts to crack. The entire crust is dislodged, and a smaller version of the alien spreads its wings.**

> I saw the first thin splitting of Mercury's shell, and the curious fluid ichor which seeped from a dying world. I watched the grisly emergence of that small, wet, scrawny thing—raw simulacrum of its monstrous parent—from the egg in which it had lain for whatever incalculable era was the gestation period of a creature vast as space and as old as time. I saw the mother bird stretch forth its giant beak and help its fledgling rid itself of a peeling, needless shell; stood horrified to watch the younger bird emerge and flap its new, uncertain wings, drying them in the burning rays of the star which had been its incubator.

**Massive projects are started to drill through the Earth's crust and set off hydrogen bombs in the hope of killing the hatchling before it destroys the Earth.**

> "I believe," he told a special emergency committee appointed by the President, "the bird has come to hatch the brood of young it deposited God knows how many centuries ago about that incubating warmth which is our sun. Its wisdom or instinct tells it that the time of emergence is now; it has come to help its fledglings shed their shells.
>
> "But we know that mother birds, alone and unaided, do not hatch their young. They will aid a struggling chick to crack its shell, but they will never begin the liberating action. With an uncanny second sense, they seem to know which eggs have failed to develop life within them. Such eggs they never disturb.
>
> "Therein, gentlemen, lies our only hope. The shell of Earth is forty miles in thickness. We have our engineers and technicians; we have the atomic bomb. If mankind is to live, the host to which we are but parasites must die. That is my only solution. I leave the rest to you."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> In the flat desertland of America was frantically thrown together the mechanism for mankind's greatest project—Operation Life. To this desert flew the miners, the construction engineers, the nuclear physicists, the men skilled in deep-drilling operations. There they began their task, working night and day with a speed which heretofore had been called impossible. There they are working now, this minute, as I write, fighting desperately against each passing second of time, striving with every means and method they know to reach and destroy, before the bird comes, the life within our world.

**The story ends with the narrator saying something like "this morning the Earth began to knock."**

> So there is no real ending to this story. As I said before, I don't know why I'm bothering to write it. The answer is not ready to be given. If we succeed, there will be ample time to tell the tale properly—the whole great story, fully documented, of the battle being waged on the hot Arizona sands. And if we fail—well, then there will be no reason for this writing. There will be none to read it.
>
> The bird is not the greatest of our fears. If when it comes from Venus it finds here a quiet, lifeless, unresponsive shell, it will move outward—we believe and pray—to Mars, then Jupiter, and thence beyond.
>
> That is the end we hope to bring about. Soon, now, our probing needles will penetrate Earth's shell, will dip beneath the crust and into the tegument of that horror which sleeps within us.
>
> But we have another more tormenting fear. It is that before the mother bird approaches us the fledgling may awake and seek to gain its freedom from the shell encasing it. If this should happen, Abramson has warned, our work must then proceed with lightning speed. For let that fledgling once begin to knock, then it must die—or all mankind is doomed.
>
> That is the other reason why I write. To keep from thinking thoughts I dare not think. Because:
>
> Because early this morning, Earth began to knock. . . .

Comment: Obviously correct!  Thank you!  I actually read it in *Earth Is the Strangest Planet*; looking at the listing, I remember at least "Rock Diver," "Narrow Valley" and "The Rotifers."