# Giant space birds hatching out of planets; short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

First of all it is **not** this very recent question
[Giant alien flies into the solar system; the rocky planets are its eggs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216633/giant-alien-flies-into-the-solar-system-the-rocky-planets-are-its-eggs).

**That** question reminded of a very similar story I read in the late 1960's/early 1970's.

What I remember:- The planets in our Solar System were shuddering and splitting apart almost simultaneously.

However earthquakes and volcanic activity had already caused Humanity to be offworld and fleeing in massive starships.

As they watch, vast birds emerge from the planets and flock together before flying away.

The story ends with somebody asking ***"If the planets are eggs, what then are the suns?"***

Comment: [Born of the Sun](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44021) by Jack Williamson is the other notorious "planets are eggs" story, but while it sort of matches your description it doesn't contain the line you quote.

Comment: Damnit.  Years ago, I had a collection of well known science fiction stories that were done as cartoons.  This story was in it, as well as "Who Goes There" and "Microcosmic God."  I'll have to see if I can figure out what book it was.  It is at my mother's house on another continent, so I can't just root it out of the bookshelf.

Comment: [It seems to have been this issue of "Starstream,"](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Starstream/Issue-3?id=126018) which means the story I remembered was "Born of the Sun" by Jack Williamson.

Comment: "Who Goes There" wasn't in that edition of Starstream, though.

Comment: I wonder that line I distinctly remember about "if the planets are eggs etc"  is maybe from the 'editorial blurb/intro to this yarn in whatever anthology I read it in. I know (think!) there was a human space fleet observing the hatching

Comment: "Born of the Sun" ends with three people watching the planets hatching - then over optimistically planning to rebuild the human race from two men and one woman (all three the only survivors.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to suggest [Born of the Sun](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44021) by Jack Williamson because it's the other well known *planets are eggs* story and it matches your description in many respects. However the line you quote doesn't appear in the story. I can't find a line even remotely similar to it.

The story is more a novella than a short story and it has a definite *pulp era* feel to it, complete with a heroine being abducted by a Fu Manchu like character. I read it in Asimov's Before the Golden Age anthology. It starts with the protagonist, Foster Ross, working on his spaceship design (which he will of course finish just in time to escape from the doomed Earth). His uncle, Barron Kane, turns up to explain that he has just escaped from *the Cult of the Great Egg*, a fanatical cult based in the Gobi desert. The cult revealed to Kane that the Earth is an egg that will shortly hatch.

The outer planets start to hatch first and the hatching proceeds inwards. The first signs are when Pluto (which was still a planet back then :-) wanders away from its orbit, then the same happens to a moon of Neptune and so on. Finally Earth's Moon hatches.

Foster plans to save as many people as possible in his newly designed space ship, but there's a battle with the cultists and in the end only Foster and Barron escape, Foster's sweetheart June having been kidnapped by the cultists. However it turns out that June had managed to escape and had hidden on the ship. The story ends with Foster, Jane and Barron in the spaceship watching the Earth hatch.

Barron dies at the end and his final words are:

> “There will be many Planets, and greater ones. The new, free race will be greater than the old. The children of Foster and June will conquer space, to the farthermost one of you!”

Comment: I'm accepting this thanks, I must have confused the space fleet issue. Also, as remarked in comments, the final line may have been an editorial intro to the story in some anthology. Thanks